# Intermittent null CLOB returned from query of non-null CLOB field

Tags: c#, .net, oracle11g, odp.net, clob

I am querying a table that contains a single CLOB field that is NOT NULL. Occasionally queries return a result set where the CLOB returned is null, an obvious constraint violation. I can work around the problem with a re-read, but that's a hack.

It does not appear to be the driver or the ORM we are using, as a Java based driver and unmanaged Oracle client used by a third party application appears to have the same problem. I'm not doing any kind of parallel I/O. The query executes in a single transaction and there is no contention on the table AFAIK.

Here's the setup.

- DB: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
- Driver: Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 12.2.1100 via NuGet (aka ODP.NET)
- .NET: 4.6
- ORM: NPoco 3.9.3

What could cause this, and is there a fix? Is it perhaps a driver bug? The problem seems to occur under load but not always.

With my coworkers we've several theories, the most prominent being that at a low level the driver is asynchronously loading the CLOB as we begin accessing the result set. That seems far-fetched and obviously buggy. Another theory is that sometimes? the conversion from CLOB to string fails.

Comment: You aren't providing any code details, so it is nearly impossible to answer, but I will say that Oracle Clobs have an EMPTY state which is NOT the same as null but might be being converted into a null by improperly written code on your end. Also you are using an extremely old version of ODP.NET and should try out the latest 12.2 driver.

Comment: Will try updating the driver. I didn't post code, because the code didn't seem to matter (two very different setups with the same behavior). I'm willing to bet it's a driver bug after everything we've tried.

Comment: Driver is the latest. Same behavior.

Comment: Are the internal LOBs properly initialized, eg. with an INSERT/UPDATE statement using `EMPTY_CLOB()`?

Comment: No the field is initialized with actual content.